# How do I search one field with multiple values in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to construct a search query such that I get back paragraph_ids 1 and 2 for document_id 299.  The way my query is currently constructed this does not happen.

Here are some representative data:

```
{
    "document_id": "299",
    "date": "2014-06-21",
    "paragraph_id": "1",
    "text": "foo"
}

{
    "document_id": "299",
    "date": "2014-12-24",
    "paragraph_id": "2",
    "text": "bar"
}

{
    "document_id": "314",
    "date": "2014-07-01",
    "paragraph_id": "1",
    "text": "I thought what I'd do was, I'd pretend I was one of those deaf-mutes."
}

{
    "document_id": "272",
    "date": "2014-08-01",
    "paragraph_id": "2",
    "text": "I saw the best minds of my generation destroyed by madness starving hysterical..."
}
```

Here is my query:

**Query 1**

```
{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{"range": {"date": {"lte": "2015-01-01","gte": "2014-01-01"}}}],
        "should": [{"match": {"paragraph_id": "1"}}, {"match": {"paragraph_id": "2"}}],
        "filter": [{"bool": {"should": [{"match_phrase": {"document_id": "299"}}]}}]
        }
    }
}
```

I expect my results to contain paragraph_ids 1 and 2 for document_id 299.  *However my results contain document_ids 299, 314, and 272.*

When I search for a single paragraph_id I get the expected result.  Here is an example query:

**Query 2**

```
{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{"range": {"date": {"lte": "2015-01-01","gte": "2014-01-01"}}},
                 {"match": {"paragraph_id": "1"}}],
        "filter": [{"bool": {"should": [{"match_phrase": {"document_id": "299"}}]}}]
        }
    }
}
```

When I include multiple match paraphraph_id statements I get no results back:

**Query 3**

```
{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{"range": {"date": {"lte": "2015-01-01","gte": "2014-01-01"}}},
                 {"match": {"paragraph_id": "1"}},
                 {"match": {"paragraph_id": "2"}}],
        "filter": [{"bool": {"should": [{"match_phrase": {"document_id": "299"}}]}}]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write the query such that I *only* get back paragraph_ids 1 and 2 for document_id 299?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`must` is the same as logical AND operator and `should` is the same as logical OR operator**

In the third search query, you are having a [`must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause with three conditions that include range query and match queries for `paragaraph_id`- 1 and 2, but there is no single document that satisfies all three conditions. So, by this query, you will get an empty search result.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [                        // note this
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "lte": "2015-01-01",
              "gte": "2014-01-01"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "paragraph_id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "paragraph_id": "2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "document_id": "299"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You need to use the `should` clause for multiple `paragraph_id`, as shown below

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "lte": "2015-01-01",
              "gte": "2014-01-01"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "paragraph_id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "paragraph_id": "2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "document_id": "299"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66342299",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "document_id": "299",
          "date": "2014-06-21",
          "paragraph_id": "1",
          "text": "foo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66342299",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "document_id": "299",
          "date": "2014-12-24",
          "paragraph_id": "2",
          "text": "bar"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I'm going to ask another question because this one isn't exactly the problem I'm having.  The issue is that document_id 299 really has 3 paragraphs with ids from 1 to 3.  I want just paragraphs 1 and 2 and not 3.  When I run your query, it's like my query #2, I get the third paragraph.

Comment: Your answer address the question as posed.  I realized I need a new question to address the issue more specifically.